# only one function from class intilized in main function of c++

Tags: c++, function, class

I just wrote a simple program that has two functions in a class. Problem is when I called them from `main()`, only the first function executes and the program terminates without calling the second function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class exp{
public:
    string name;

public:
    string fun1(){
        cout<<"please enter value for first function  ";
        cin>>name;
        cout<<"yourname from first function is  ";
        cout<<name;
        return 0;
    }
    string fun2(){
        cout<<"Please enter value for second function  ";
        cin>>name;
        cout<<"yourname from second function is ";
        cout<<name;
        return 0;
    }


};
int main(){
    exp b1,b2;
    cout << b2.fun1();
    cout << b1.fun2();

}
```

The output is

```
please enter value for first function preet
yourname from first function is preet
```

Comment: First, remove anything that you can while keeping the behaviour. By the end, your code could be a main function with one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, try this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class exp
 {
  private:                  // changed from public to private
  string name;    
  public: 
  int  fun1()               // changed from string to int
   {
     cout<<"\nplease enter value for first function  ";
     cin>>name;
     cout<<"\nyourname from first function is  ";cout<<name<<endl;
     return 0; 
   }
  int fun2()                // changed from string to int
   {
     cout<<"\nPlease enter value for second function  ";
     cin>>name;
     cout<<"\nyourname from second function is ";
     cout<<name<<endl;
     return 0;
   }    
 };
int main()
 {
   exp b1,b2;
   b2.fun1();            // removed cout
   b1.fun2();            // removed cout    
 }
```

The problem was you were using `cout` inside your functions, yet you were also calling them inside a function, that is `cout<<b2.fun1();`. This is not a good practice.

There was also the problem that the type of your functions were string, but they were returning an integer.

You had also made `name` as `public` which just defies the use of OOP. So I made it `private`.

Cheers......Hope this solves your Problems..  :)

Comment: How does using `std::cout` to print the result of a function that uses `std::cout` matter (in terms of bugs, not best practices)?

Comment: It prints the return value as well. If the return value was something like a white space, it wouldn't have mattered. I just pointed it out. I've edited my post

Answer (score 1):

You are returning `0` while the return type is `string`. Constructing a `std::string` from a null pointer is not allowed. You could use `return "";` instead.

Comment: thanks bro, i think i should use void in function because  function doesn't return anything to main.